# How to make a variable that changes depending on user input in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make something just random for fun, so this is what  i have:

```
:login
echo Please login.
set /p x=Username: 
if %x% == example.user goto home
if not %x% == example.user goto login

:home
echo Welcome 'example.user'!
```

I want it to change to example.user or whatever the user logs in as, so how would I do that? I don't know how to do that in batch. All code and help are amazing. Thank you all sooooo much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
:login
echo Please login.
set /p x=Username: 
if "%x%" == "%USERNAME%" (goto home)
if not "%x%" == "%USERNAME%" (goto login)

:home
echo Welcome %x%!
```